# How do I model a join table with parent-child tables?

Tags: database-design

I have a table, `VisitTest`, that joins patient visits (`Visit` table) to diagnostic tests (`Test` table) given during that appointment. The `Test` table is a superclass (parent table) of tables containing actual tests. Each child table has the test parameters and results (1).

The `Test` table contains metadata. Columns like `id`, `name`, `description`, `status`, etc are stored here. The child tables (inherit, in OOP terms, from the `Test` table) and have their own test-specific fields. Each test parameter is its own column. The child tables have an id column that represents the test instance. For example we may have 10 tests but each test was given 100 times so we have 1000 test instances.

For some reason, I can't figure out how to model the relationships. That's where I need help.

Am I missing another join table to make this work? How to I join the visit number to the instance of the test? Given a visit id, how do I find the specific tests given during that visit? How do I model the relationship between the parent and child tables?

Here are three tables I have. The TestABC table is a specific test and there will be many other tests like it. The visit table and everything related to it, minus the linkage to tests, is complete.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnV1] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Visit]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestABC](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Parameter1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Parameter2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_TestABC]
```

(1) I deleted my earlier question about choosing between key-value pair and entity-type tables. I opted to avoid venturing down the KVP road due to less-than-blissful report building experience with KVP and my preference for strongly-typed values.

Comment: So if you have `VisitTest`, which joins `Visit` and `Test`, and you setup the `Id` column in your Child test table (`TestABC`, etc...) as both the PK of `TestABC`, and as a FK to `Test`... doesn't that meet all your requirements?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If a given Test is done/performed/created only because of a Visit, and only because of *that*  visit, then add VisitId as a foreign key to the Test table, to indicate the parent/owning/defining Viist.

Types/Subtypes are much trickier.

If  TestABC is a subtype of Test, then in TestABC, the primary key should be TestId, and it should also be a foreign key to table Test column TestId. [*I never use just “ID” for surrogate primary key columns – it gets too confusing too fast when writing complex joins.*]

Sounds like there are lots of Test subtypes. Sounds also like they’re exclusive, e.g. a Test with data in table TestABC cannot also have data in table TestXYZ, or any other subtype table. To determine which type of Test it is, you’d have to query each subtable to find what kind of test it is. That, however, is just awful, so instead add a TestType column to the Test table. Probably best to have a lookup table as well (TestType), with foreign keys to ensure no wayward test types sneak into the system.

A subtle issue is how to prevent data from being entered into multiple subtypes tables for  a given Test. To guarantee accuracy is perhaps overly-fussy, but if you consider peace of mind and relational integrity as worth the price, do this:

- Add a TestType column to each subtype table
- Add  a check constraint to each subtype table such that the TestType column can *only* be set to the appropriate code for that subtype
- In the Test table, build the primary key on {TestId, TestType}
- In each subtype table, build a foreign key on {TestId, TestType} back to table Test (on the two columns)
- Voila, you can only add a row to a subtype table if the "owning" Test entry is set with that table's TestType.

Comment: I find this article very helpful for mapping objects to database: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MappingInheritance