# Unique id shared between multiple tables sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, database-schema

I have a problem with my site. The site has multiple entities: Articles, Posts, Reviews ... orund 6 types. Now I am introducing the possibility for a user to rate an item (it can be any of these entities)

I created a table Votes (int Id primary key, int ItemId, nvarchar(30) Ip, datetime Timestamp, int VoteValue). Here I will store all votes and their ips.

My problem is that I must have ItemID unique ... but my database already have items of various types having the same id. All tables started the ids from 0. What options do you see for my design in order to be able to store all votes in a single table?

Comment: Does it have to be that ID column that's unique? Couldn't you have a column for type as well (which identifies which table it should be from) and it be a unique combination?

Comment: you are right ... but I was thinking at the performance impact if I will make the query to get all votes of an item

Comment: Are you trying to limit votes to one per item, or are all items one of a kind?

Comment: I dont understand why you cant simple add a IDENTITY column to your  table Votes? I may not have understood what you whant. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is trying to assign multiple meanings to the field "ItemId", which will lead to the issues you are encountering.  If I were to see "9500" in that field, how would I know what that means?

I would suggest dropping the ItemId field and creating "crosswalk" tables between Votes and the other entities.

For example, your entities:

```
+-----------+
| Articles  |
+-----------+
| ArticleId | PK
| ~ snip ~  |
+-----------+

+-----------+
| Posts     |
+-----------+
| PostId    | PK
| ~ snip ~  |
+-----------+
```

... etc ....

Your votes table:

```
+-----------+
| Votes     |
+-----------+
| VoteId    | PK
| ~ snip ~  |
+-----------+
```

Your "crosswalk" tables:

```
+--------------+
| ArticleVotes |
+--------------+
| ArticleId    | PK, FK to Articles
| VoteId       | PK, FK to Votes
+--------------+

+--------------+
| PostVotes    |
+--------------+
| PostId       | PK, FK to Posts
| VoteId       | PK, FK to Votes
+--------------+
```

Note that in your crosswalk tables, you would create a composite primary key consisting of both the FK references to the appropriate entities, thereby ensuring uniqueness.

In my experience, this is an appropriate normalized approach to the domain you describe.

In querying, to get the votes for the Articles (for example) simply INNER JOIN Articles through ArticleVotes to Votes.  To get all Votes, simply query Votes.

Additionally, I would suggest creating an IPAddresses table and FKing to that in your Votes table to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

An option that wasn't mentioned was GUIDs.  If you use GUIDs in your Articles/Posts/Reviews/etc. instead of the int primary keys you could rely on these to be unique.  I am not saying this is the route you should use as it can add additional overhead to store/search GUIDs rather than ints.

I would recommend adding the type field to the votes table and having it be part of the key.  It sounds like you had already thought about this idea but are worried about performance.  If you are worried about performance do some tests to ensure the table queries meet your needs before putting the changes into production.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to convert your set of disparate tables into a type/subtype set. A discussion of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709547/how-do-i-model-a-join-table-with-parent-child-tables). The (perhaps considerable) downside is that you’d have to refactor all your tables… but then you’d have one Id (perhaps “ItemId?) used to uniequely identify all your Item Types.